# Pandas: remove duplicate multiple conditions based on column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big multi-index dataframe with lots of columns with lots of duplicate timestamps.

Now I want to drop duplicates but the problem is I want to keep the max value for column 1 and last value for other columns.

```
timestep        headers
        col1    col2    col3
1       2       5       6
1       1       3       4
2       3       5       6
2       4       7       8


Should give


timestep        headers
        col1    col2    col3
1       2       3       4
2       4       7       8
```

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is. Also, can you provide the data in a more convenient format?

Comment: convenient as in?
I want to merge the duplicated timestamps where I keep the max value from col1 and the last values from other columns... So the 1st df should be converted to the 2nd one..

Comment: @AjitWadalkar Convenient as in, for example, running `df.to_dict()` and including that output in your question. As it now stands, anyone trying to answer your question must also spend time reproducing your issue and data sample.

Answer (score 1):

If you [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on the index you can take the `.max()` of each column:

```py
df.groupby(df.index).max()
```

```
   col1  col2  col3
1     2     3     4
2     4     7     8
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I updated the example dataframe. I want the max of only one column and for other columns, it should keep the last value.